# I need to reference an image in my code, from two different pages (with different paths to /images)

Tags: html, relative-path, information-hiding

So, I have a function:

```
public string genSomeHtml(){
   //Gen some html including and image called foobar.gif
}
```

Now, I want to call genSomeHtml() from two different pages, but they have different paths to /images.  So, I can't exactly use "../../images/foobar.gif" and I'd rather not pass a param to tell me where to look.  Afterall, the calling page shouldn't care about how the html is rendered, it just needs to work.

any ideas?

Comment: Is this Java + Tomcat? or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General answer: Output your image with an absolute uri, instead of relative.
so `<img src="images/myphoto.jpg">` becomes `<img src="http://localhost/images/myphoto.jpg">`

If that wasn't the right answer, please rephrase your question and add examples.

Comment: While this would have worked, it wasn't the exact solution I went with.  I will accept though, as it is technically a correct answer.